# angularjs - can promises timeout?

Tags: angularjs

When using Angular's $q service, do promises eventually timeout on their own?

Some background: I have an Angular service making POSTs to a remote server, which in turn is querying a MySQL database and supposed to send back the result. Some queries return in under a second, while other are expected to take up to 20 minutes. The issue is that, after exactly 4 minutes after sending the request, there's a net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (in Chrome dev tools).

We're using $q and $http in a service to facilitate the POSTs.

```
queryDB: function(query, page) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.post(BASEPATH + "/filter", {data: query, page: page, token: localStorage.auth}, {timeout: 1200000})
  .success(function(response) {
    deferred.resolve(response);
  })
  .error(function(error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
  })

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Here's the controller to which the promise returns:

```
$scope.queryDB = function(page) {
var query = formatQuery($scope.query);
FilterService.queryDB(query, page).then(function(res) {
  ...
})
```

I know the call is arriving at the server thanks to some simple test logging. but what's odd to me is the dev console indicates that [the connection was always "stalled"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIAF1.png) and never reached the server in the first place.

Again, this only happens with queries taking more than 4 minutes, otherwise it behaves normally. So my best guess is that Angular is not waiting long enough to resolve/reject the promise. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Angular has nothing to do with that. It has a timeout but it is defaulted to 0 (unlimited). My bet is that your browser or the OS or Firewall are closing the connection.

Comment: I think your http request is timing out. According to [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in arguments section you can see that it gives you option to set the timeout of a request

Comment: @GurbakhshishSingh we've set the timeout very high already (see first code block) with no luck

Comment: @ggallo have you ever resolved this issue?

Comment: @JustGoscha I never actually solved the timeout problem, I used a process queue on the server and made the client poll for updates. I think Simone is probably right.